# Plotting Shapefile rgdal ggplot extra lines plotting?

Tags: r, ggplot2, kml, shapefile, rgdal

I'm trying to add rain catchments to a plot. I've successfully plotted the points etc, and have done so by converting my kml to a shapefile using [GISconverter](http://converter.mygeodata.eu/) and following [this turorial](http://spatioanalytics.com/2014/02/20/shapefile-polygons-plotted-on-google-maps-using-ggplot-throw-some-throw-some-stats-on-that-mappart-2/) on plotting Shapefile Polygons. However when I plot my graph I get extra lines occurring. They seem to be a 'return to origin' line. I've pointed some out with blue arrows in [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TCubf.jpg).
[image]
However I'm unsure if that is the cause, I've plotted the map data in [Google Maps](https://www.google.com/maps/d/edit?mid=1WR2qreKPMoENA_osyrwf0KM2OgE), to check the mapping and its correct there.
Please see my code below; also here for a [Google Drive share folder](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0Bzy5Nu8FgnI4ZDRrSE9aVVNjU28&usp=sharing) with all the code and data sets etc (it may take a moment for the files to upload).

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I've not much experience with kml or any geography/map files.
Thank you in advance.

```
`### BVB313
library(ggrepel)
###MAPS
#Read in Map.cvs
P.Map<- read.csv(file = file.choose())
myLocation <- c( lon = 152.911033,lat = -27.344505)
#get map
myMap <-get_map(location=myLocation,source="google", color="color",zoom = 9, maptype = c("terrain"))
ggmap(myMap)
#plot map with points
P.out<-ggmap(myMap)+ 
  #geom_polygon(aes(x=long, y=lat), size=1,color='red', data=Neighborhoods, alpha=0)+
  geom_point(aes(x = Longitude, y = Latitude), data = P.Map,
  alpha = .5, color="darkred", size = 3) +
  geom_label_repel(data=P.Map,aes(x = Longitude, y = Latitude, label = Location),nudge_x = 0.20,nudge_y = -0.025)+ 
  labs(title = "Sampling Locations", x = "Longitude", y = "Latitude")+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size=15, face="bold", vjust=2)) +
  annotate("text", x = 152.25, y = -28, label = "10km", hjust=-0.1, vjust=-0.2)+
  annotate("segment", x = 152.25, xend = 152.25, y = -27.91, yend = -28, size = 1.5) 
P.out

#ggsave(filename = "BW Map.png" ,plot = P.out, width = 8,height = 8,dpi =600,units = "in" )

# Catchment Area Shape File Layer
#set directory to working location!!!!
########################
install.packages('rgdal')
install.packages('ggplot2')
library(rgdal)
catchment_layer <- readOGR(".","polylines5")
catchment_layer <- spTransform(catchment_layer, CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"))

library(ggplot2)

catchment_layer <- fortify(catchment_layer)
P.out_catchment_layer <- P.out + geom_polygon(aes(x=long, y=lat), size=.2,color='red', data=catchment_layer, alpha=0)
P.out_catchment_layer
ggsave(filename = "Catchment_Map.png" ,plot = P.out_catchment_layer, width = 8,height = 8,dpi =600,units = "in" )`
```

Comment: Would be helpful if you provide reproducible data to check on your issue. Anyway, just a hunch... instead of `geom_polygon` try `geom_path` for your polylines object.

Comment: I have, please see the Google Drive share, has all my data, workspace history, code and produced images. If there is a better way to share my data I'd gladly do so.

And yes however I have an interest in using the polygon function as being able to shade area's would be beneficial.

Comment: Same problem, does this one solve your question? [ggplot2 facet plot of shapefile polygons produces strange lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28465040/ggplot2-facet-plot-of-shapefile-polygons-produces-strange-lines)